Analyse data from LoRa data transfer STM32WLE5JC
I have a program that sends data between 2 WIO E5 Mini devices, but I don't know how to extract the actual data from the packets. I am using LoRa and the subghz phy middleware.
#include "platform.h"
#include "sys_app.h"
#include "subghz_phy_app.h"
#include "radio.h"

/* USER CODE BEGIN Includes */
//[JT]
#include "utilities_def.h"
#include "stm32_seq.h"
#include "stm32_timer.h"
#include "main.h"
#include "stdio.h"
/* USER CODE END Includes */

/* External variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN EV */
//[JT]
#define RECEIVER
//#define TRANSMITTER
#define BUFFER_SIZE     10
extern UART_HandleTypeDef huart2;
/* USER CODE END EV */

/* Private typedef -----------------------------------------------------------*/

/* USER CODE BEGIN PTD */
/* USER CODE END PTD */

/* Private define ------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PD */
#define TRANSMIT_PERIOD_MS 2000  /* set Tx period of timer to 2 seconds */     //[JT]
/* USER CODE END PD */

/* Private macro -------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* USER CODE BEGIN PM */

/* USER CODE END PM */

/* Private variables ---------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Radio events function pointer */
static RadioEvents_t RadioEvents;
/* USER CODE BEGIN PV */
uint16_t BufferSize = BUFFER_SIZE;   //[JT]
uint8_t Buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];         //[JT]
/* USER CODE END PV */

/* Private function prototypes -----------------------------------------------*/
/*!
 * @brief Function to be executed on Radio Tx Done event
 */
static void OnTxDone(void);

/**
  * @brief Function to be executed on Radio Rx Done event
  * @param  payload ptr of buffer received
  * @param  size buffer size
  * @param  rssi
  * @param  LoraSnr_FskCfo
  */
static void OnRxDone(uint8_t *payload, uint16_t size, int16_t rssi, int8_t LoraSnr_FskCfo);

/**
  * @brief Function executed on Radio Tx Timeout event
  */
static void OnTxTimeout(void);

/**
  * @brief Function executed on Radio Rx Timeout event
  */
static void OnRxTimeout(void);

/**
  * @brief Function executed on Radio Rx Error event
  */
static void OnRxError(void);

/* USER CODE BEGIN PFP */
static void Rx_Process(void);  //[JT]
static void TransmitPacket(void);    //[JT]
/* USER CODE END PFP */

/* Exported functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/
void SubghzApp_Init(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN SubghzApp_Init_1 */

  /* USER CODE END SubghzApp_Init_1 */

  /* Radio initialization */
  RadioEvents.TxDone = OnTxDone;
  RadioEvents.RxDone = OnRxDone;
  RadioEvents.TxTimeout = OnTxTimeout;
  RadioEvents.RxTimeout = OnRxTimeout;
  RadioEvents.RxError = OnRxError;

  Radio.Init(&RadioEvents);

  /* USER CODE BEGIN SubghzApp_Init_2 */
  //[JT]
//#ifdef TRANSMITTER
//  APP_LOG(TS_ON, VLEVEL_L, "******TRANSMITTER******\n\r");
////  Radio.SetTxConfig(MODEM_LORA, TX_OUTPUT_POWER, 0, LORA_BANDWIDTH,
////                     LORA_SPREADING_FACTOR, LORA_CODINGRATE,
////                      LORA_PREAMBLE_LENGTH, LORA_FIX_LENGTH_PAYLOAD_ON,
////                      true, 0, 0, LORA_IQ_INVERSION_ON, TX_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
//#endif
//#ifdef RECEIVER
//  APP_LOG(TS_ON, VLEVEL_L, "******RECEIVER******\n\r");
////  Radio.SetRxConfig(MODEM_LORA, LORA_BANDWIDTH, LORA_SPREADING_FACTOR,
////                    LORA_CODINGRATE, 0, LORA_PREAMBLE_LENGTH,
////                    LORA_SYMBOL_TIMEOUT, LORA_FIX_LENGTH_PAYLOAD_ON,
////                    0, true, 0, 0, LORA_IQ_INVERSION_ON, true);
//#endif
  Radio.SetTxConfig(MODEM_LORA, TX_OUTPUT_POWER, 0, LORA_BANDWIDTH,
                        LORA_SPREADING_FACTOR, LORA_CODINGRATE,
                        LORA_PREAMBLE_LENGTH, LORA_FIX_LENGTH_PAYLOAD_ON,
                        true, 0, 0, LORA_IQ_INVERSION_ON, TX_TIMEOUT_VALUE);
  Radio.SetRxConfig(MODEM_LORA, LORA_BANDWIDTH, LORA_SPREADING_FACTOR,
                      LORA_CODINGRATE, 0, LORA_PREAMBLE_LENGTH,
                      LORA_SYMBOL_TIMEOUT, LORA_FIX_LENGTH_PAYLOAD_ON,
                      0, true, 0, 0, LORA_IQ_INVERSION_ON, false);
  Radio.SetMaxPayloadLength(MODEM_LORA, BUFFER_SIZE);
  //Radio.SetChannel(RF_FREQUENCY);
  Radio.SetChannel(914900000);
  SUBGRF_SetDioIrqParams( IRQ_TX_DONE | IRQ_RX_TX_TIMEOUT | IRQ_RX_DONE,
          IRQ_TX_DONE | IRQ_RX_TX_TIMEOUT,
          IRQ_RX_DONE,
          IRQ_RADIO_NONE );


//#ifdef TRANSMITTER
//  Buffer[0] = 'S';
//  Buffer[1] = 'T';
//  Buffer[2] = 'M';
//  Buffer[3] = '3';
//  Buffer[4] = '2';
//  Buffer[5] = 'W';
//  Buffer[6] = 'L';
//  Buffer[7] = '_';
//  Buffer[8] = 'T';
//  Buffer[9] = 'X';
//
//  /* Add delay between TX and RX =
//  time Busy_signal is ON in RX opening window */
//  HAL_Delay(Radio.GetWakeupTime() + TCXO_WORKAROUND_TIME_MARGIN);
//
//  UTIL_TIMER_Create(&timerTransmit, 0xFFFFFFFFU, UTIL_TIMER_ONESHOT, TransmitPacket, NULL);
//  UTIL_TIMER_SetPeriod(&timerTransmit, TRANSMIT_PERIOD_MS);
//  UTIL_TIMER_Start(&timerTransmit);  // start transmitting packets every 2s
//#endif
//
//#ifdef RECEIVER
//
//  UTIL_SEQ_RegTask((1 << CFG_SEQ_Task_Rx_Process), UTIL_SEQ_RFU, Rx_Process);
//  UTIL_SEQ_SetTask((1 << CFG_SEQ_Task_Rx_Process), CFG_SEQ_Prio_0);
//
//#endif
  /* USER CODE END SubghzApp_Init_2 */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN EF */
//[JT]

void SendRadioData(void){
    TransmitPacket();
}

void GetRadioData(void){
    Rx_Process();
}
static void Rx_Process(void)
{
  APP_LOG(TS_OFF, VLEVEL_L, "\n\r");
  APP_LOG(TS_ON, VLEVEL_L, "Radio Rx\n\r");
  Radio.Rx(0);
  Radio.Read(0);
}

static void TransmitPacket(void)
{
  Radio.Send(Buffer, BufferSize);
}
/* USER CODE END EF */

/* Private functions ---------------------------------------------------------*/
static void OnTxDone(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN OnTxDone */
  //[JT]
  APP_LOG(TS_ON, VLEVEL_L, "OnTxDone\n\r");
  Radio.Sleep();
  //UTIL_TIMER_Start(&timerTransmit);  //Transmit packet in 2s
  /* USER CODE END OnTxDone */
}

static void OnRxDone(uint8_t *payload, uint16_t size, int16_t rssi, int8_t LoraSnr_FskCfo)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN OnRxDone */
  //[JT]
  APP_LOG(TS_ON, VLEVEL_L, "OnRxDone\n\r");
  APP_LOG(TS_ON, VLEVEL_L,  "RssiValue=%d dBm, SnrValue=%d\n\r", rssi, LoraSnr_FskCfo);

  Radio.Sleep();
  BufferSize = size;
  memcpy(Buffer, payload, BufferSize);

  APP_LOG(TS_OFF, VLEVEL_L,  "%s \n\r", Buffer);

  //UTIL_SEQ_SetTask((1 << CFG_SEQ_Task_Rx_Process), CFG_SEQ_Prio_0);
  /* USER CODE END OnRxDone */
}

static void OnTxTimeout(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN OnTxTimeout */
  /* USER CODE END OnTxTimeout */
}

static void OnRxTimeout(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN OnRxTimeout */
  /* USER CODE END OnRxTimeout */
}

static void OnRxError(void)
{
  /* USER CODE BEGIN OnRxError */
  /* USER CODE END OnRxError */
}

/* USER CODE BEGIN PrFD */
/* USER CODE END PrFD */


This is the subghz_phy_app.c and it is a modified version of https://github.com/stm32-hotspot/STM32WL-SubGHz-PhyBasic-Tx-Rx/tree/main. I have tried looking at interrupts to extract the data, but there is nothing I can find as to how to call the function on an interrupt.
I have also read the STM32WLE5JC user manual and looked at many examples, but they are all using the full LoRaWAN stack, whereas I just want to use the base LoRa protocol to send packets from one master to many slaves.
I am quite new to the STM32 world and HAL programming in general, so any advice or help would be greatly appreciated.

Look at the OnRxDone() function. That's the callback where the data is received.

The function OnRxDone() is a callback, and its argument *payload is a pointer to your received data. The memcpy(Buffer, payload, BufferSize) function copies your data to Buffer. You can see it in the debug Live Expression section. You probably need to pause the debug to read this because of low power mode.
